# Nginx folder redirection without changing the url

Tags: nginx, routing

I want to redirect an old path to a new one **without changing the url** and keeping the suffix of the url for the redirection:

> dev-osm.blah.com/NYC/v2/site/links?key=a12345

redirect to

> dev-osm.blah.com/NYC/v1/site/links2?key=a12345

I tried the following configuration but without any success:

```
server {
   server_name  dev-osm.blah.com
.
.

location / {
  if($query_string ~ "(^|&)key=($|&)")
    rewrite ^/NYC/v2/site/links$ /NYC/v1/site/links2?key= redirect;
}
```

Comment: Remove `redirect`.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @drookie any other suggestions?

Comment: You probably need to parse `$args` separately.